# How do I connect Katalon studio to my Database?

Tags: database-connection, mamp-pro, katalon-studio

- Mamp Pro 4.3 Licensed.
- Katalon Studio 5.2
- MacOS High Sierra 10.13

Im having this issue:
[image]

This is my mamp ports:
[image]

I have already tried: 
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB_NAME 
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/DB_NAME 
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:8888/DB_NAME 
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:8889/DB_NAME

Answer (score 1):

Try jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/DB_NAME

Comment: thank you for answering, I tried it, its not working.